# Will django be around for the next ~5~ years?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, django, frameworks

I'm currently working as an asp.net developer,
At work were looking at some open source based toolkits to do some new projects in

Ive been given complete freedom to chose what I want to work with (be it rails, django, zend) with one requirement...

It can't be a here today gone tommorow framework..

So my question is.. Is django gonna stick around or will it die soon?

I know this is hard to say cause the industry moves so fast!

Comment: No one knows.  I'm not sure what you expected to read.  General trend is up over the last few years: http://www.google.com/trends?q=django+python&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=0

Comment: My magic 8 ball said "outlook good". Any other question about the future?

Comment: It's open source.  Where do you think it's going to go?

Comment: 1) Subjective and Argumenative. 2) Off topic (not related to programming) 3) Not a real question (We can't read the futue). Needless to say, voted to close.

Comment: Ah man... Sorry guys that was a stoopid question, guess I'll just use whatever feels right =P

Comment: The problem of being "here today and gone tomorrow" is a far greater risk for proprietary, closed-source software.  Sometimes open source software becomes abandoned. But once it's truly free it's never truly "gone" even if no one has maintained it in years.  Even so it's far less common than with proprietary software.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm sure you know, this is extremely subjective and any answer would be nothing but speculation.

In general, I like to reference the [ThoughtWorks Technology Radar](http://www.thoughtworks.com/sites/www.thoughtworks.com/files/files/thoughtworks-tech-radar-august-2010-US-color.pdf) for this kind of speculation.  Unfortunately, I don't see Django or even Python anywhere on it.  I find that a little odd, since Python is a perfectly good language for rapid web development (among other things).  So this may be an exception to the rule.  But it's still a pretty good guide in general.